# Android studio user create tabs and edit

Tags: android

I am making an app that is called bookmarker.
The app let you make "tabs" where the user can store a link and a name for it.

I have everything setup (webview, webview client, settings tab, App Preference manager, ...)

I am working in a Navigation Drawer Activity .

What I want to achieve :

The user can create tabs with link and names in it.
The user can add/remove/edit tabs in the settings menu.

I just cant get an idea for how to manage this , hope you can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Now as you wished an example for removing an tab:

Following adapter you could use to set up your listview:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)
```

For object you could use an ArrayList with object that represent an Tab

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    //Verify operation by user
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getActivity());
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete the selected Tab?")
           .setPositiveButton("Yes delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   //Call a delete method

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No don't delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // Nothing to do
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
  }
});
```

Creating a new Tab:

```
final Button buttonCreate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createTab);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if(v.equals(buttonCreate){
                 //Accessing UserInput
                 EditText userInputName =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                 String inputName = userInputName.getText().toString();
                 EditText userInputURL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.url);
                 String inputUrl = userInputURL.getText().toString();
                 //Call a creation method with inputName and inputUrl
                 }
             }
         });
```

Comment: I thought of a file where the user could write the name and url and that you could have a method that gets all of what is in the file and make it in to a tab.

Comment: You also could use the SQLite DB which is build. You could than for example modify it within the settings and later read all tabs within the onCreateView().

Comment: Ok lets say that I want 2 buttons create a tab and remove a tab how do I do that ?

Comment: Well for removing i would suggest an listview. With an onItemClick() which will ask the user if he really likes to remove the selected item. And than just use a sql statemant which deletes the specified tab. And for creating you would use 2 editText views, where you can write in the name and the url. In the click method of the button you would read the text from the editText views and than write it to your sqlite db.

Comment: Ok then but how do I realize it?

Comment: I will modify my post

Comment: @CaptainStony hope this helps you. There you find all you need to know about sqlite [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)